# Azure VM monitoring default health criteria alert notification

Tags: performance, azure, virtual-machine, alert, monitoring

New to Azure, Just wanted to understand if it possible to get a notification like email, slack message or a webhook push, when the default VM health criteria is breached (e.g. when `Disk Avg. Disk sec/Read`).

Below link says  `All health criteria are pre-configured to alert when the unhealthy condition is met`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/vminsights-health#alerting-and-alert-management

[image]
But how to configure the action group/ external notification.

I tried a solution mentioned in below link which tells to `enable default notificationSettings`, but no  luck in getting the slack / email.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/understanding-health-criteria-in-azure-monitor-for-vms/

```
{
    "nextLink": null,
    "value": [
        {
            "etag": null,
            "id": "/subscriptions/SUB_ID/resourcegroups/RG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SonarQube/providers/Microsoft.WorkloadMonitor/notificationSettings/default",
            "name": "notificationSettings/default",
            "properties": {
                "actionGroupResourceIds": [
                    "/subscriptions/SUB_ID/resourceGroups/RG/providers/microsoft.insights/actionGroups/Webhook_gateway",
                    "/subscriptions/SUB_ID/resourceGroups/RG/providers/microsoft.insights/actionGroups/Slack%20Webhook",
                    "/subscriptions/SUB_ID/resourceGroups/RG/providers/microsoft.insights/actionGroups/VM%20monitoring"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Microsoft.WorkloadMonitor/virtualMachines/notificationSettings"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Any update? Did that help?

Comment: Not really. What I am really looking for is to be able to have notification on default health criteria which comes with `inSight`. I know how to use those metrics and create alert with action group. But why to create a alert (classic or not) when there exists already some rule to evaluate VM health

Answer (score 1):

Classic metric alerts in Azure Monitor provide a way to get notified when one of your metrics cross a threshold.
Using this, you can send notifications to your email addresses as well as call a webhook when the alert fires.

Refer to these docs:

[Create, view, and manage classic metric alerts using Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-classic-portal)

[Have a classic metric alert notify a non-Azure system using a webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-webhooks)